# "cases" command in f1000Research journal

Tags: latex

I am writing my paper in the F1000journal template. When I want to use "cases" for defining a piecewise function, it shows something like a table. Here's [f1000research link](https://f1000research.com/for-authors/article-guidelines?gclid=Cj0KCQjw4uaUBhC8ARIsANUuDjVyL2l7YFbrIdZ-SLU5P8ok8-Xdo1ft-b_dtf12tR1aixx8IXFeiUYaAqbKEALw_wcB)
and these are the command section of the template

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{f1000_styles}

%% Default: numerical citations
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

%% Uncomment this lines for superscript citations instead
% \usepackage[super]{natbib}

%% Uncomment these lines for author-year citations instead
% \usepackage[round]{natbib}
% \let\cite\citep

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

I am writing the following equation

```
f(n) = \begin{cases}
  n/2  & n \text{ is even} \\
  3n+1 & n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the rowcolours your template is setting

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{f1000_styles}
%% Default: numerical citations
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

%% Uncomment this lines for superscript citations instead
% \usepackage[super]{natbib}

%% Uncomment these lines for author-year citations instead
% \usepackage[round]{natbib}
% \let\cite\citep

\rowcolors{2}{}{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{equation}
f(n) = \begin{cases}
  n/2  & n \text{ is even} \\
  3n+1 & n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]